# Setting MasterPage property from a custom control on a Content page

Tags: c#, asp.net, oop

I know this subject has been discussed before in other threads but my question is regarding style and OOP principles rather than how to. We have a situation where we have a MasterPage a Content page and a custom control that is used in the Content page. The MasterPage is in the MyNamespace namespace and exposes a property MasterTitle and we need to set this property from the custom control (MyControl). We have also added <%@ MasterType VirtualPath="~/Site.Master" %> so that we can reference the Master page from the content page. One programmer has used the following line of code to set the MasterTitle property:

```
   ((MyNamespace.Site)Page.Master).MasterTitle = "Some Title";
```

Another programmer has done something a lot more complex. In the custom control he has declared a delegate:

```
   public delegate void SetMasterTitleDelegate(string masterTitle);

   public SetMasterTitleDelegate SetMasterTitle;
```

And then in the Content page's Page_Init():

```
  MyControl.SetMasterTitle = (masterTitle) => { Master.MasterTitle = masterTitle; };
```

In Page_Load() event of MyControl the MasterTitle property is set:

```
  SetMasterTitle("Some Title");
```

I would like to know the pros and cons of each method of accomplishing this task as it pertains to OOP principles.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to accomplish this. You can create a property "Title" on each contentpage, and in the setter of the property you set the title of the masterpage. Another way could be to implement an interface on each contentpage which can be used as a 'contract' for the masterpage. You can use a base where you set the masterpage title and set it from the contentpage.

But personally i would choose (and use) the first approach of you. Clean and simple to follow.

But OOP-wise I think MS would be advising to use a sitemap to set titles and build menus/breadcrumps.

Answer (score 0):

Let's talk about the approaches first :

**Approach 1 :** The first approach is quite simple and straightforward and the least complicated method. It could be used without much overhead. *Conclusion - Good Method*

**Approach 2 :** The second approach seems a lot more complex and I would personally avoid it. In the bigger context, each custom control or child page that you develop would require such methods.

The only other approach I can think of if creating and implementing an interface on the masterpage with the properties and methods that you generally would like to reference in the master page. So

```
public interface IMasterContract {
    public string Title {get; set;}
}
```

You could then create a base class that inherits from System.Web.UI.Page and implement the same interface in the base class. Here you could decide if the title you want to set needs to be set to the masterpage if it exists or do anything else you want to if it does not.
So,

```
public abstract class AppPage : System.Web.UI.Page, IMasterContract
{
    public string IMasterContract.Title {
        get
        {
            if(this.Master!=null && this.Master is IMasterContract)
            {
                return ((IMasterContract)this.Master).Title;
            }
            else
            {
                //return the title from whatever control or variable you've stored it in
            }
        }
        set
        {
            if(this.Master!=null && this.Master is IMasterContract)
            {
                ((IMasterContract)this.Master).Title = value;
            }
            else
            {
                //set the title to whatever control or variable you want to stored it in
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The approach I've stated is generally useful for large applications where maintainability is  a huge variable.
Changes can be made centrally that would reflect across the application.

For smaller apps or if the functionality you are trying to attempt is limited to a couple of locations, I wouldn't go to the extent of doing what I've displayed, I'd rather go with approach 1.